# Python Selenium Run Chromedriver from CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to run ChromeDriver from CLI?

When I SSH into a Machine and run the following commands:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running selenium in c9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213684/running-selenium-in-c9)

Answer (score 0):

Just run the executable directly:
`sudo /path/to/chrome/driver/chromedriver`
You will get something like: `Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174...`

If thats not what you want and you want to execute it through python then that error code `127` is because it cannot find the executable or you are not running that python script with super user privileges.
Hope it helps!